# Broadcasting with Laravel Echo, laravel-echo-server and socket.io is not working

Tags: laravel, websocket, redis

I've setup websockets with Laravel sucessfully with an own implementation.But, after many hours of trying and reading every piece of documentation I could find, I do need further help.

```
"laravel-echo": "^1.5.2",
"socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
```

This is my **.env** file details

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
 "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
```

**ExampleEvent file**

```
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('test-event');
    }

    public function broadcastWith(){
        return [
            'data' => 'key'
        ];
    }
```

My **Bootstrap.js**

```
window.Echo.channel('test-event')
    .listen('ExampleEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

When Implementhing

Laravel-echo-server:

> [10:03:50 PM] - F07Nv9alc-Bsh3LEAAAB joined channel: test-event
>   [10:04:16 PM] - F07Nv9alc-Bsh3LEAAAB left channel: test-event
>   (transport close) Channel: test-event Event: App\Events\ExampleEvent

Redis:

> 1548349380.228566 [0 127.0.0.1:53929] "EVAL" "-- Pop the first job off of the queue...\nlocal job = redis.call('lpop', KEYS[1])\nlocal
>   reserved = false\n\nif(job ~= false) then\n    -- Increment the
>   attempt count and place job on the reserved queue...\n    reserved =
>   cjson.decode(job)\n    reserved['attempts'] = reserved['attempts'] +
>   1\n    reserved = cjson.encode(reserved)\n    redis.call('zadd',
>   KEYS[2], ARGV[1], reserved)\nend\n\nreturn {job, reserved}" "2"
>   "queues:default" "queues:default:reserved" "1548349470"
>   1548349380.228773 [0 lua] "lpop" "queues:default"

**This statement is being repeated continuously..**

> Moreover there is no output in browser

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `redis` configuration inside `laravel-echo-config.json` file so it knows from where to `"ask for messages"`, an example:

```
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
        "host": "http://127.0.0.1"
        "port": "6379"
    },
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error now, when i start echo server: 
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://127.0.0.1 http://127.0.0.1:6379
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)

Comment: You need to put in your address and port where you have `redis` connection open at

Comment: It is open at this port only

Comment: when i removed that, i got this in redis server on making attempt in browser: 
"RPUSH" "queues:default" "{\"displayName\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\ExampleEvent\",\"job\":\"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call\",\"maxTries\":null,\"timeout\":null,\"timeoutAt\":null,\"data\":

Comment: {\"commandName\":\"Illuminate\\\\Broadcasting\\\\BroadcastEvent\",\"command\":\"O:38:\\\"Illuminate\\\\Broadcasting\\\\BroadcastEvent\\\":7:{s:5:\\\"event\\\";O:23:\\\"App\\\\Events\\\\ExampleEvent\\\":1:{s:6:\\\"socket\\\";N;}s:10:\\\"connection\\\";N;s:5:\\\"queue\\\";N;s:15:\\\"chainConnection\\\";N;s:10:\\\"chainQueue\\\";N;s:5:\\\"delay\\\";N;s:7:\\\"chained\\\";a:0:{}}\"},\"id\":\"Bz0WsB4JiS02oqEPmDrugxFgYO4kMuCw\",\"attempts\":0}"